# how to update Wordpress plugins from external website with nodejs?

Tags: plugins, rest-api

I'm building a website in nodejs. what I want to achieve is the following:

- Connect to different wordpress websites using the API REST (this step is done)
- List all the plugins available in those website (this step is done) - in the example I only put one.
- I want to know if there is any update available for the plugins, and update from my custom nodejs site.

This is my code for listings the plugins, I can retrieve the custom version, but I can't find the latest version.

```
    const siteUrl = "https://example.com/";
    const plugins_endpoint = "wp-json/wp/v2/plugins/";
        const pluginsUrl = siteUrl + plugins_endpoint;  
    const token = Buffer.from(`${username}:${password}`).toString("base64");
    
        const config = {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Basic ${token}`,
      },
    };
    
    async function getPluginList() {
      const response = await axios.get(pluginsUrl, config);
      return response.data;
    }
    
    getPluginList()
      .then((data) => {
        data.forEach((element) => {
          console.log("Plugin name: ", element.name);
          console.log("status: ", element.status);
          console.log("current Version: ", element.version);
          console.log("Textdomain: ", element.textdomain);
          console.log("Links: ", element._links);
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
```

Comment: are there parts missing from your question? There is no plugins endpoint in WordPress so it's not clear where `pluginsUrl` is referring to or what you're interacting with, and there are important parts of your question missing that are needed to understand. Can you edit your question to be fully self contained and understandable on its own with no missing parts? Your question doesn't make sense right now

Comment: is this question about the `wp-json/jetpack/v4/plugins` REST API endpoint?

Comment: I update the question, for better understanding ( I hope )

Answer (score -1):

Assuming a private plugin, not available via the repository, there are several search results for 'wordpress private update' that might be helpful.

In fact, I recall doing it once several (many) years ago, but can't find how I did it. (And I seem to recall posting the answer here on SO, but can't find that either.)

But, one of the search results is here https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/self-hosted-plugin-update.html . The process is a bit complex.

I have a few private plugins that I have written that I use on the sites I manage. But since I wrote them, I know when they change, and I manually update on the sites I manage. They aren't anywhere else, so don't have to worry about any automatic processes.

**Added**

If you are looking for a plugin that will update other sites, there are a few that already do that. But they require their plugin on the additional sites, to provide an 'authentication' to the admin area of that other site.

One I use is "Infinite WP", which is a manager for multiple sites. Each site has their plugin installed, and then the 'master' site accesses those sites (via the plugin) to perform updates and other functions. Works quite well.

If you are looking for a way to 'enumerate' plugins on another sites that you do not own or manage, then that sounds a bit 'black-hacky', and I can't help you there.

Comment: Thank's Rick, I will take a look at the link. But I'm building an entire site in nodeJS/react.

Comment: @Fede you need to mention that as well as everything else that's missing from your question, Rick is trying to answer the literal written question you asked, if you have extra requirements or context it must be mentioned or it doesn't count

Comment: Rick I don't think the OP is asking how to provide updates for their plugin, it's not 100% clear what Fede is asking but it looks like the plugins they're asking about are plugins plural, not just their own plugin, aka other peoples plugins. They're also asking about an unknown API

Comment: @TomJNowell - probably. I added to my answer, but the OP is still not clear with his question, so a bit of a guess. Thanks...